# Is it possible to use MicroStrain IMU 3DM GX4-25 in Hector SLAM

Tags: hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use IMU 3dm Gx4 25 in **Hector SLAM.**
The package of IMU 3dm Gx4 comes from the website:

https://github.com/KumarRobotics/imu_3dm_gx4

However, I got a problem when I used Hector SLAM.
After using **roswtf**, it showed that there was no **tf** message.
Furthermore, the problem might be come from **hector_imu_attitude_to_tf**.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220548/is-it-possible-to-use-microstrain-imu-3dm-gx4-25-in-hector-slam/) by [elton](https://answers.ros.org/users/25020/elton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As long as your sensor publishes sensor_msgs/Imu you can use it. Your Problem looks like you do not have transformation between robot-base and IMU sensor. Did you add it into urdf file (or urdf.xacro)? If not you should do it.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0